# How to get scrapy xpath output in single item

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i am extracting a particular xpath expression as:

```
#item["post"]=response.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'node-')]/div//p//text()").extract()
```

when i export the file in .csv format, the content is coming in separate line as:

```
Hi, Steps:,
1. Enabled calendar module.,
2. Enabled date api, date pop up, date views.
```

I want to export the post in a single line as follows:

```
Hi, Steps:, 1. Enabled calendar module., 2. Enabled date api, date pop up, date views.
```

Please help me out to solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options you could do.

First add multiple `Field`s to your item. But I guess this is not what you want.

The **real cause** of your problem is that when you use `xpath('//...').extract()` you get back a list of results. A solution for this would be to join the results together:

```
item["post"] = ' '.join(response.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'node-')]/div//p//text()").extract())
```

In your case it can be that even the elements have a line break so I would get rid of those new lines too if it is the case. For this you could use `map(unicode.strip, ...)`.

Comment: Sir, i tried your approach but it is still giving me output in separate lines. The raw data i want to scrape is in following form:  ----- <p>Hi, </p>
<p>Steps:</p>
<p>1. Enabled calendar module.<br />
2. Enabled date api, date pop up, date views.<br />. --------- So, how to use that map() method...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the map() method worked fine for my scenario: `item["post"]=map(unicode.strip,response.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'node-')]/div//p//text()").extract())`